# Is there a way to send data from html tags to php?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to alter the functionality of submit button for some reasons. If have called a JS function which is called by clicking submit button but i have no idea how can i manually send my data from html tags to php variables. Below is the short description of code.

```
<html>
<body>
<input class="inputtext" id="email" name="email" type="text"></div>
<input value="Submit" name="v4l" id="login" class="inputsubmit" type="button" onclick="myFunction();return false">
<script>

function myFunction() {
  var TestVar =document.getElementById("email").value;
    document.write(TestVar);
//store data of testvar to php
}

</script>
<html>
<body>
```

I know it can be done by form but i need it this way.

Comment: You're either going to need to use a form or do an ajax request.

Comment: Start there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

Using a PHP form would be a really simple solution: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
You could pretty much post it strait to the PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are comfortable with jQuery.

Try

```
$("#login").click(function(){
        var email= $("#email").val();
        jQuery.post(
                    "*your parsing url*",
                    {email:email},
                    function(data){
                       // Data returned from the ajax call

                    }
                )
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library makes this, and many other tasks, very simple:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<form id="myForm">
  <input class="inputtext" id="email" name="email" type="text"></div>
  <input value="Submit" name="v4l" id="login" class="inputsubmit" type="button" onclick="myFunction();return false">
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'yourcode.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: jQuery('#myForm').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      alert('The data was sent, and the server said '+response);
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more information.